# What's the best way to convert string array into a table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given some array parsed from a CSV as follows (don't worry about the parsing part, just consider this array as the start point).

say: 
`['name,age,city', 'tom,12,new york','john, 10, los angeles']`

Such that the first index is the column names, what's the best way to convert this into a table. I was thinking of using numpy and pandas to create a dataframe, but what would be the most memory/time efficient way to convert to do this? Then I am planning do some data analysis and create some new features. Is there something in the standard python library I can use or is pandas the best way to go about this? If I was to use just builtin functions how would I go about this? At the end I would need to combine the features back into the original form of an array.

Comment: In `pyspark` you can read the data from a csv and save it as a table.

Comment: pandas can certainly handle this, and if you need to do some further analysis, it can certainly make things easier. but so could just the standard library csv module, depending one what exactly you need to do. I think this question may be too broad.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Say I couldn't use any external libraries, what would be my best bet?

Comment: If you have a csv file use pandas read_csv method

Comment: The csv module then, if you don't want external dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builtins only (aside from `pprint` for printing):

```py
import pprint

data = [
    "name,age,city",
    "tom,12,new york",
    "john, 10, los angeles",
]
cols = None
out_data = []
for line in data:
    line = line.split(",")

    # We don't know the columns yet; must be the first line
    if not cols:
        cols = line
        continue
    out_data.append(dict(zip(cols, line)))

pprint.pprint(out_data)
```

Using the `csv` standard module:

```
import csv
import io
import pprint

data = [
    "name,age,city",
    "tom,12,new york",
    "john, 10, los angeles",
]

reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data)))
out_data = list(reader)

pprint.pprint(out_data)
```

Both approaches output the expected:

```
[{'age': '12', 'city': 'new york', 'name': 'tom'},
 {'age': ' 10', 'city': ' los angeles', 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is the way to go. You do not need to parse values. Instead you can just use [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) functionality to create a dataframe out of your CSV file and do feature generation/extraction or data cleaning on this frame. Python standard library does not/should not offer such capability out of box.

To gather your values as a Python list at the end of the day use `df.values.tolist()`.

`pandas` has C code in critical sections which makes it orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: python has the `csv` module that parses csvs.

Comment: I know python has a `csv` module that parses CSV files. I pointed out Python should not offer `pandas` capabilities built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for efficiency sake, but as far as an easy way to convert it to a table goes using pandas would be the best option. I would use pandas.read_csv for it.